# Postgres Macro, Concat Interval Days and Table name to use in Query

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I need to create a macro or function that takes in two parameters, and concats them together after a basic data manipulation. Then this text string should be able to be used in any other query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getData (_table text, _days text)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$

    SELECT $1 || to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - ($2 || ' days')::INTERVAL, 'YYYYMMDD');
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;

select * from getData('opportunity', '4') limit 10;
```

So what I am expecting from this is to actually get the same result as if I executed

```
select * from opportunity20151030 limit 10;
```

Instead I am getting "opportunity20151030"

EDIT:

The reason we need this is because my employer is doing a nightly snapshot of our salesforce data, about 17 objects in all. Thats why I can't return a table. Returning a table needs to specify the columns. But we need to be able to query a variety of tables. This really needs to be just a small utility macro. This way we can have one query, to generate graphs that compare data from today and a week ago. This can even be something inside of pgAdmin itself, and is not restricted to being postgresql function. Is there a way I can execute the function and use the result inline in another query. I spent an hour playing around with

Execute 'select * from $1' using getData('opportunity', '4')

type queries, but apparently the LANGUAGE specified changes what can and can't be used in terms of compatible SQL statements.

Thank You!

Comment: This looks like a horrible data model. You should need such a function in the first place. Why don't you use partitioning/inheritance for this?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. My employer just wants to write a set of queries once, to generate reports from nightly snapshots we take from salesforce. This doesn't have to actually be in postgres, and can be in a tool like pgAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your function is returning exactly what you asked for... the name of the table you want to look in.

Now, while you can do a function that returns some table's data, the function must know the "structure" of that data. Which means that you can't use it for any table but those that share the same structure (same number of fields, same data types in the same order). Guessing about your table's name i will say that is an inherited table and a function like the one belowe can do the trick for any derived (inherited) table from opportunity

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getData (_table text, _days text, _limit int default -1)
    RETURNS SETOF opportunity AS
$func$
DECLARE
    table_name text;
    limit_clause text = ' ';
BEGIN
    SELECT _table || to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - (_days || ' days')::INTERVAL, 'YYYYMMDD') INTO table_name;
    IF _limit > -1 THEN
        limit_clause = ' LIMIT ' || _limit;
    END IF;
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM ' || table_name || limit_clause; 
    RETURN;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And use it like:

```
select * from getData('opportunity', '4', 10);
```

PS1: i put the limit as one extra parameter in the function, but because that parameter has a default value you can ignore it when calling the function and that will return all values. i put it there because otherwise the function will return all rows in the table and limit after that.

PS2: i would avoid doing this unless you really think is needed, because this cannot be optimized if put as part of a larger query.

Comment: Thank you so much for your contribution. But we have 17 tables in all that we are taking nightly snapshots of. What we need is very simple and more like an excel formula. Maybe its something we can do in pgAdmin? Or maybe a way I can execute the function and use the result inline in another query?

Comment: Have this 17 tables different structures? The nightly snapshots are the ones that looks like "opportunity20151030"? (ie: with the date as part of the name)

Comment: Yes they do, we are taking snapshots of different SObjects by using the metadata to create a postgres tables, and then populating them. So not only do the 17 tables differ in structure, the same SObject could change from one day to another, if a modification was made in Salesforce, which would be reflected in postgres. Thank You!